# Variable Javascript dentro de un botón history.back

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tengo un enlace "'javascript:history.back()'", dentro de este botón:

```
<a href='javascript:history.back()' style='padding:0.6em;background:linear-gradient(to right,#44d9e6,#0978ef);font-size:14px;color:#f5f5f5;border-radius:5px'>VOLVER</a>
```

El mismo lleva al cliente a la página anterior usando Javascript...
Lo que quiero implementar y no lo consigo es cómo redirigir al cliente a la página principal cuando no existe una página anterior en el historial del cliente. Por que en la experiencia del usuario, el botón no realiza ninguna acción mientras no exista una página anterior.

Creo que me he explicado lo más certero posible. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deberías capturar el evento onClick y hacer la validación, algo así:

```js
document.getElementById('link_ir_atras').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (history.length === 1) {
        // No hay historial, redirigir a la página principal
        open('https://google.com');
    } else {
        // ir atrás
        history.back();
    }
})
```

```html
<a href="#" id="link_ir_atras">Ir atrás en historial</a>
```

Comment: ¿Incluiste el código javascript que te entregué?, este es el que se encarga de asociar el evento onClick y si has navegado antes (que en teoría si), te devolverá a la página anterior, de lo contrario, te mandará a Google.